# how to add android:labelfor to multiple text fields

Tags: android, android-xml

```
android:labelFor="@+id/tip10et"
android:labelFor="@+id/tip15et"
android:labelFor="@+id/tip20et"
```

it is showing error android:labelfor is already specified for one text field

Comment: could you explain a bit more what you want?

Answer (score 1):

labelFor is an accessibility attribute.

If you have a textview that serves at the label for another field ( say an edittext )
you can reference the id of the edit text in the labelfor of the textview.

Answer (score 1):

**`android:labelFor`**

> Specifies the id of a view for which this view serves as a label for accessibility purposes. For example, a TextView before an EditText in the UI usually specifies what infomation is contained in the EditText. Hence, the TextView is a label for the EditText.

You can't do that as is. You should use multiple *label* views, each one should have an `android:labelFor` to their respective *labeled* View.

BTW: Could use the same string resource for all of them.

### Example (minimalist)

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img1"/>
<TextView android:text="@string/sametext" 
          android:labelFor="@id/img1" />
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img2"/>
<TextView android:text="@string/sametext" 
          android:labelFor="@id/img2" />
<ImageView android:id="@+id/img3"/>
<TextView android:text="@string/sametext" 
          android:labelFor="@id/img3" />
```